# Prolog singleton variable in branch

Tags: prolog

I have the below code:

```
loc_sucs(R, C, result(A, S)) :-
    loc_sucs(R, C, S), 

    Rm is R - 1, 
    A \= move-north;
    R = 0; 
    o(Rm, C);
    r(Rm, C, S);

    Rp is R + 1, 
    dim(Z, _),
    A \= move-south;
    R = Z; 
    o(Rp, C);
    r(Rp, C, S);

    Cp is C + 1, 
    dim(_, W), 
    A \= move-east;
    C = W; 
    o(R, Cp);
    r(R, Cp, S);

    Cm is C - 1, 
    A \= move-west; 
    C = 0; 
    o(R, Cm);
    r(R, Cm, S).
```

And I'm getting the singleton warning for Rm, Cm, Rp, Cp, Z and W. Why am I getting this warning if all of these variables are used more than once?

Comment: say `listing(loc_sucs)` to see how Prolog understood your code. Putting `;` at the end is highly problematic!

Comment: Note the `;` in your code, which is "or". So there are "or" paths that do not use the variables more than once.